# Reducing cyclomatic complexity

Tags: java, exception-handling

I ran a sonar analysis on my code and it told me the cyclomatic complexity is too high (sonar's limit is ten branches).

Here is my code:

```
public void myMethod(){
  try{
  // do something
  catch(SomeException e){
    throw new WrappingException("issue when doing something " + e.getMessage(), e);
  }
  catch(AnotherException e){
    throw new WrappingException("issue when doing something " + e.getMessage(), e);
  }
  // lots of other Exceptions
}
```

Basically, I want to catch a large set of Exceptions, (maybe always processing the same behaviour). I read the question [Catching multiple types of exceptions when writing JSON](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12767/when-to-catch-a-general-exception) but I don't use Java 7 (with which I could have all Exceptions in one catch statement) and I do not really want to catch ALL Exceptions, since I want my code to fail in a case I did not expect.

Is there any alternative that would involve fewer branches?

NOTE: What I want to achieve here is not to recover from any Exception, but to categorize the Exceptions. An upper layer is in charge of handling Exceptions, but for this purpose, Exceptions need to be properly categorized.

Comment: If the Exceptions that you are interested in catching share common super classes (but not as far up the ancestor stack as `Exception`) then you **could** catch the super class rather than each subclass. If they don't, is your method doing too much?

Comment: I call a constructor by reflection. That gives me already 6 Exceptions to catch. But I agree, I should maybe split the rest of my method.

Comment: Shame it is Java 6, as if you look at what they added (fixed, was silly not to have this before) here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ReflectiveOperationException.html that would have cut down your necessary catch blocks!

Comment: ah indeed it's cool that they decided to use inheritance on Exceptions. Indeed, if we switch to Java 7, I'll update the code.

Comment: @JohnMark13 I found a way to split my method, it looks nicer now. Thanks, you can actually post your comments as an answer.

Comment: What does `myMethod` throw in its signature?

Comment: @Duncan Jones nothing necessarily. in that case let's assume WrappingException is an unchecked exception.

Answer (score 2):

As JohnMark13 stated in the comments above, if the exceptions you want to catch share a common supertype (possibly besides the basic `Exception` class), then you could catch the supertype instead of all the subtypes. If you have created the `SomeException` and `AnotherException` classes yourself, then I strongly suggest that you make them extend a common custom exception type.

Also, I think that since you **rethrow** the exceptions (or at least most of them), then catching the general `Exception` is OK. Or, you could first catch all `RuntimeException`s, rethrow them directly, and then check the rest and possibly throw your `WrappingException`. Consider this:

```
public void myMethod() {
    try {
        // do something
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // We don't need to wrap these, so we just throw the same exception again
        throw e;
    }
    catch (YourCommonSuperException e) {
        throw new WrappingException("issue when doing something " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // All other excpetions, such as `IOException` and stuff will be caught and wrapped and throwed here.
        throw new WrappingException("issue when doing something " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    // No need for any other Exceptions
}
```

Perhaps you get some extra cyclomatic complexity from the `// do something` part. If so, then you could split that part into multiple methods and possibly declaring to throw the exception from the method if needed so that it will get caught in this `myMethod()` (or catch within the method and throw some kind of `YourCommonSuperException`.

Depending on the specific `// do something` part, you might want to overlook which kind of exceptions that are thrown there. If you throw them yourself, it might be possible to change to `IllegalArgumentException`, `IllegalStateException` (which both extend `RuntimeException`) or some exception that extends `YourCommonSuperException`.